# I'm having an issue with Angularjs $invalid

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, validation

Hello,
In my code I have three inputs number in this order (I will name them first input, second input and third input for the explications) :

```
<div>
    <form name="formOpenMax">
        <div class="input-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': formOpenMax.inputOpenMax.$dirty && formOpenMax.inputOpenMax.$invalid }">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Max</span>
            <input class="form-control has-feedback" name="inputOpenMax" type="number" placeholder="Maximum" ng-model="selectedItem.range.max" min="{{selectedItem.range.min}}" >
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
<div>
    <form name="formOpenMin">
        <div class="input-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': formOpenMin.inputOpenMin.$dirty && formOpenMin.inputOpenMin.$invalid }">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Min</span>
            <input class="form-control has-feedback" name="inputOpenMin" type="number" placeholder="Minimum" ng-model="selectedItem.range.min" min="0" max="{{selectedItem.range.max}}" >
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
<div>
    <form name="formIntOpenDefault">
        <div class="input-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': formIntOpenDefault.inputIntOpenDefault.$dirty && formIntOpenDefault.inputIntOpenDefault.$invalid }">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Default</span>
            <input class="form-control has-feedback" name="inputIntOpenDefault" type="number" placeholder="Default value" ng-model="selectedItem.range.default" min="{{selectedItem.range.min}}" max="{{selectedItem.range.max}}" >
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

So what I'm trying to do is to have a proper validation. The two first `input` are a range between two value that the user enter.
If the user enter a text instead of a number the `input` will become red. But there is a problem :

⇨ In the first `input` the `min` value is the number that the user enter in the second `input` but the validation doesn't take it in consideration and the input doesn't become red.

⇨ In the second `input` the `max` value is the number that the user enter in the first `input` but the validation doesn't take it in consideration and the input doesn't become red once again. But the `min` value is `0` and when we put for exemple `-1` the validation works

⇨ In the third `input` the `min` value is the number that the user enter in the second `input` and the `max` number is the number of the first input. And again the validation isn't workink.

For each inputs, when I put an incorrect number, the validation doesn't work but a tooltip appear to tell me to enter a bigger/little number so it detect the value but the value is not invalid.

Do you have an idea of what to do to make it work ?

Comment: Seems to be working just fine. See this: http://plnkr.co/edit/sdKAjFIq3Npp7hDAUkFW?p=preview

Comment: It looks like it was an issue that's been fixed so you may just need to update to a new version of angular. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2404

Comment: Oh yes, I think it can come from the version. I'm using an old version. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's an issue with previous versions of Angular and fixed in 1.3.14:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2404